# JSON args are not collected in parameter of POST Method

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Following is a contract in IService interface

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/service1/Add", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        MyClass AddProperty(MyClass propertyArgs);
```

Following is my implementation

```
public MyClass AddProperty(MyClass args)
        {
   //I always get args null here
}
```

Following is my code to call above service

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "url",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": '{"userid": 342507,"name": "markand"}'
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The problem is that my service is enable to collect the data sent from ajax. I get my args parameter always null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works. I'm using it and it is working fine for me

```c#
var data = {"userid": 342507,"name": "markand"};
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSONstring.make(data),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    async: true,
    timeout: 90000,
    success: function (items) {
        //Your success handling here
    },
    error: function (obj, timeout, message) {
        //Your error handling here
    }
});
```

Editted: your setting must have only the data to be parsed in this example

Comment: use "raw" instead of form-data to send the info, then you are going to be able to paste your json (after changing combobox beside)